# MarketingCloudConfig doesn't exist in version 8.1.4

Tags: marketing-cloud, android, salesforce-sdk-android

I am trying to implement Android SDK in my app using steps below.

https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/sdk-implementation/implement-sdk-google.html

I have added maven repo

```json
repositories {
  maven { url "https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/repository" }
}
```

Then added the SDK dependency

```json
dependencies {
  implementation "com.salesforce.marketingcloud:marketingcloudsdk:8.1.4"
}
```

However, I cannot find `MarketingCloudConfig` library. It just doesn't exist. So this code snippet here doesn't compile.

```kotlin
    SFMCSdk.configure(applicationContext as Application, SFMCSdkModuleConfig.build {
      pushModuleConfig = MarketingCloudConfig.builder().apply {
        //.....
      }.build(applicationContext)
    }) { initStatus ->
       //...
    }
  }
```

I already have Firebase initialised in my app. I have tried both adding the core library and removing it. It doesn't help. Anyway, this library isn't inside Firebase. And even worse firebase-core doesn't have version 23 as the tutorial suggests.

```
Follow the Android Firebase setup documentation. 
When you add the Firebase core dependency to your module gradle file, use 
com.google.firebase:firebase-core:23.x.x.
```

Here the final version is 21.
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.firebase/firebase-core

So it makes me think that the installation steps in this documentation are wrong. Looks like it's a copy paste from old documentation and not verified. Because if I add the version 6.4.0 instead of 8.1.4 it just works. MarketingCloudConfig library could be imported.

Looks like this package is removed from 8.x. If so where?

How to make this work for v8.x? Am I skipping a step here?

Captured a gif for what's happening:
[image]

Comment: I meant to say documentation not tutorial. The first official link in the question. And that is my problem. Config isn't part of the SDK. At least for the version 8.1.4. I downgraded to 8.0.9 and and now I can import it.

Comment: Can't say I'm convinced. I've tried this on my Mac and my Windows machines. I've tried it on my current project, Leaning Aplication and a project from scratch. So 2 machines and 3 different projects. All the same results. Looks like this class was made private for 8.1.4. I've attached a gif from Learning App (see my edited post above). https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGneR.gif

Comment: Invalidate caches doesn't help. I did that and even changed the operating system.

Comment: Found the issue where it's happening. The repo you created is using Gradle JDK 17 and I'm using version 11. Somehow Gradle JDK 11 cannot sync MarketingCloudConfig class (for version 8.1.4) but JDK 17 can sync both 8.0.9 and 8.1.4. Probably needs to be documented somewhere. Wouldn't expect such a breaking change between minor versions. But thanks all sorted now.

Comment: Very sorry if that offends you, sincerely that is not my intention to do so. However, that is a "breaking change" by definition. Change in the minimum version of a dependency (library or anything else) is definitely a breaking change. But it's OK to have breaking changes if that helps improve the software. One addresses those changes and moves on. That's what I'm gonna do. Anyway, it's not my intention to start a discussion here. Thank you very much for the repo and have a lovely day!